# Is a three hour layover at Delhi international airport enough to catch a flight to Newark, USA (Indian citizen)?

Tags: layovers, del

I am an Indian citizen flying AirIndia from Ahmedabad to Delhi, and after a three hour layover at Delhi airport, I fly to the US (on a student visa). Is this time sufficient to get through immigration, etc? This is part of a round-trip (US-India-US) that I booked on United/AirIndia, and I also have travel insurance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, both Ahmedabad and Delhi are in India... why would you need to go through immigration in your own country?

Comment: @MichaelC. As I understand it India's immigration service checks departing travelers, as do many other countries and the Schengen zone.  Having arrived on a domestic flight, the traveler will have to go through an exit checkpoint before boarding the departing international flight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be enough. Both AirIndia and United fly from T3, so you don't need to change terminals. You'd however would need to exit the airside and go through passport control and security again, because domestic and international departure areas are different. Passport control line might be long, but there's still plenty of time. And AirIndia seem to be very punctual nowadays - had a bunch of domestic flights in India this year, and they were always on time.

Comment: Thanks George. However I was getting very paranoid so I booked another flight with a 6 hour layover in Delhi so I feel totally at peace now :) Although I'll remember your answer for later.

Comment: That's really paranoid :) especially considering that you're on the same ticket, so if you are unable to make the connection, it is airline's fault and not yours. I'd say Delhi airport is quite efficient by Indian standards - assuming you're not flying from low-cost T1 which is much worse - but you are not.